# chromedriver can't click when running a script, but can in shell

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem in general with clicking in Chromedriver when the code is being ran by Python. This code is used in the script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://www.marktplaats.nl/")
cook_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@method='post']/input[@type='submit']"))).click()
```

It just times out giving "NoSuchElementException". But if I put those lines manually in the Shell, it clicks like normal. For what it's worth, I'm using the latest 2.40 Chromedriver and Chrome v67. Running it headless doesn't make any difference.

**EDIT**
The program actually breaks after on the third command when it tries to find an element that doesn't exist because the click wasn't completed

```
driver.get(master_link) # get the first page
wait_by_class("search-results-table")


page_2_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='pagination-pages']/a[contains(@data-ga-track-event, 'gination')]")
```

So, page_2_el command gives this exception, but only because the click before wasn't completed successfully to remove the warning about cookies.
And I'm sure the xpath search is good because it runs with geckodriver in Firefox, but won't do it here with Chromedriver.

**EDIT2** 
See a video of the bug here https://streamable.com/tv7w4 
Notice how it flinches a bit, see when it writes on the console "before click" and "after click"

**SOLUTION**

Replaced

```
cook_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@method='post']/input[@type='submit']"))).click()
```

With

```
N_click_attempts = 0
while 1:
    if N_click_attempts == 10:
        print "Something is wrong. "
        break
    print "Try to click."
    N_click_attempts = N_click_attempts+1
    try:
        cook_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@method='post']/input[@type='submit']"))).click()
        time.sleep(2.0)
    except:
        time.sleep(2.0)
        break
```

It seems that the click is now completed. I have other clicks in the script and they work fine with element.click(), this one was problematic for some reason.

Comment: `expected_conditions` returning **NoSuchElementException**???

Comment: Did you try increasing the value of wait?

Comment: @DebanjanB I will edit the question, it actually doesn't break in this line, but after. But this is because a click is not completed, even though the program passes past that point.

Comment: @SiKing I have and it fails the same. See my edit, the "cook_button=..." goes fine and program executes this command, but the click is not really done.

Comment: `//span[@id='pagination-pages']/a[contains(@data-ga-track-event, 'gination')]` - I cannot find this element on the page. Something wrong with xPath. Can you provide where is this element with this xPath?

Comment: this is "masterlink" variable: https://www.marktplaats.nl/z/auto-s.html?categoryId=91

Comment: I've put up a video so you can see exactly what happens.

Comment: It looks like the click action is performing, but the popup doesn't disappear. I had something similar and solved it by clicking twice on the button. I have implemented a small logic - if after first click everything is fine, then execute the script as usually, else wait 1 second and click second time. Try it

Comment: I put a solution which works for me, I guess you had something like that in mind.

Comment: @DoctorEvil exactly this I had in the mind. I am happy that your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Your path is correct, but I would suggest a smaller one:

```
//form/input[2]
```

And about `NoSuchElementException` - you can try to add a pause, to wait until element loads and becomes 'visible' for `selenium`. Like this:

```
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://www.marktplaats.nl/")
cook_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@method='post']/input[@type='submit']"))).click()
time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds until DOM will reload
```

According edit in the question I would suggest to add `time.sleep(5)` after clicking on the button. And for the same reason, because after clicking the whole `DOM` reloads and `selenium` should wait until reload will be done. On my computer it takes about 2-3 seconds to full reload the `DOM`.

Comment: What is the benefit of a sleep over increasing the value of wait?

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` means that in the moment when `selenium` tries to locate the element, the element was not in the `DOM`. So it throws an exception without any waiting until clickable. That's why I suggest to wait implicit, to let the browser load whole `DOM` and then locate the element

Comment: If that were correct, that would defeat the purpose of selenium waits.

Comment: `EC.element_to_be_clickable(findElem(element))` - it is a pseudo code. In this chain first will be executed `findElem(element)`. If at the moment there is no element in the `DOM` it will throw an exception without any wait in outer(element_to_be_clickable()) function.

Comment: In the original question, or in your answer, I do not see "findElem()" anywhere! That makes a big difference.

Comment: I wrote `it is a pseudo code`. `By.XPATH` finds the element

Comment: don't use static sleeps!